# Showing Continuity of a curve

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, curves

Let $f(t)=t \sin \frac 1 t$ if $0 < t \le 1$,
and $f(t)=0$ if $t = 0$.

Consider the curve $\gamma$ with parametric representation $\phi : [0, 1] → \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by
$\phi(t) = (t,f (t))$. Prove that $\gamma$ is a continuous curve which is not rectifiable.

for continuity, do I just show that $t\sin\frac{1}{t}$ is continuous on the interval given? To prove it is not rectifiable, I have to show that length of $\phi$ is infinite. Do I show the integral of the derivative of $t \sin \frac 1 t$ is infinite?

Comment: Yes, that's all you have to do.

Comment: Yes. For continuity, all you need to show is that it is indeed continuous on the interval given. You can also note that since t is continuous on the interval given, and so is sint then tsint must also be continuous on the given interval.

Comment: @topologicalmagician Note that it is $\sin\frac1t$, not $\sin t$.

Comment: @IshanDeo this is not true: to prove the rectifiability a more subtle work is required